# Add output product to a new activity

Tags: brightway

I understand that a new activity can be added to a database via

```
a = db.new_activity(
    code="A",
    name="New activity"
    )

a.save()
```

I can add an exchange to the newly created activity via

```
a.new_exchange(
    amount=1,
    input=db.random(),
    type="technosphere",
).save()
```

However, the newly created activity will not "create" a product. How do I assign an existing or new reference product to a new activity?

[image]

Comment: from [this][1] tutorial :

> Brightway will assume that the a production exchange of amount 1 in
> each node unless you tell it otherwise.

so probably something like this should work. If the activity is normalized to produce 1 unit of output, then brightway2data will do it for you

```python
a.new_exchange(
    amount=10,
    input=a,
    type="production",
).save()
```
  [1]: https://github.com/brightway-lca/from-the-ground-up/blob/main/1%20-%20The%20supply%20chain%20graph.ipynb

Comment: Thanks @Nabla. That works. You should have posted it as an answer! :)

Comment: Thanks again; However, I now noticed that the activity's reference product remains empty. Can I also add a reference product? I tried `reference_product='test'` which seems to exist but does not work the way I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db = bd.Database('someDataBase')
db.new_node(code="code", name="name", unit="kilogram", location="CN").save()

# this should do it but your ref product will be set to None
# if you want that

act = db.get('code')
act['reference product'] = 'whatever'
act.save()

# now if you add a production exchange it will also keep the ref product
act.new_edge(input=act, amount=1, type='production')
```

There is probably a better way to do it, this works for me.